# Cycle in Directed graph to vector

Tags: c++, recursion, graph

I created a class of a directed graph and a method for finding if graph has an Euler cycle and updating a vector accordingly.Is there any optimization or a nicer way to do this.

```
class Graph {  
private: 
    int V;          // No. of vertices  
    list<int> *adj; // Pointer to array of lists  
    bool cycleHelper(int v, bool visited[], bool *reStack, vector<int> &path) const; // Helper for cycle()  

public: 
    Graph(int V);                   // Constructor  
    ~Graph();                       // De-constructor Who wants to live forever when love must Die  
    void addEdge(int u, int w);     // function to add an edge to graph  

    bool cycle(vector<int> &path) const; // Returns True if Graph has a circle, and sets path to its route  
};  

Graph::Graph(int V) {  
    this->V = V;         // Set Graph nodes  
    adj = new list<int>[V]; // V-dimention array of lists  
}  
Graph::~Graph() {  
    delete[] adj;  
}  

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int w) {  
    adj[u].push_back(w); // Add u to v's list.  
}  

bool Graph::cycleHelper(int v, bool visited[], bool *recStack, vector<int> &path) const {  
    if (visited[v] == false) {  
        // Mark the current node as visited and not in recursion stack  
        visited[v] = true;  
        recStack[v] = true;     

        for (auto i : adj[v]) {
          if ( i == path[0]) return true;
          else if (!visited[i] && cycleHelper(i, visited, recStack, path)){  
              path.push_back(i); 
              return true;
            }  
          else if (recStack[i]){  
              path.push_back(i);  
              return true;
            }  
        }  
    }  
    recStack[v] = false; // remove from recursion stack, I don't need u any more 
    return false;  
}  

bool Graph::cycle(vector<int> &path) const {  
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited and not part of recursion stack  
    bool *visited = new bool[V];  
    bool *recStack = new bool[V];  
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {  
        visited[i] = false;  
        recStack[i] = false;  
    }  
    // Call the  helper function 

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++){  
        path.push_back(i);  
        if (cycleHelper(i, visited, recStack, path)) {  
            //path.push_back(i);
            reverse(path.begin(),path.end());
            //if (path.begin()[0] == path.end()[-1]) path.pop_back();  
            return true;  
        }  
        path.clear();  
    }  
    path.clear();  
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this code is a solution to a problem on geeksforgeeks.org, using parts of a provided snippet. If this is the case, please include that in the question (preferably with link to the problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General stuff

- `#include`s are missing
- missing `using namespace std;` (which by itself is discouraged, especially in header files).
- `Graph::cycle`s `path` result contains not only the cycle, but alse the vertices that led there (e.g. in `A -> B -> C -> B`, `A` would be included in `path` though it is not part of the cycle). This might or might not be intended.
- Inconsistency: `Graph::cycleHelper` takes `visited` as `bool[]`, but `recStack` as `bool *`, even though the usage for both is the same.
- `if(visited[v] == false)` can easily be rewritten to `if(!visited[v])`
- `Graph::cycle` treats `path` as if it has full control over all elements already present. This behavior might be unexpected by users of the class and should at the very least be thouroughly documented.

## Memory management

- `Graph::cycle` leaks both `visited` and `recStack`.
- `Graph::addEdge` never checks whether its parameters are in the valid range. If they aren't, there might be accesses to out-of-bounds memory.

These issues can be fixed by using appropriate data structures and error checking. Generally, prefer using RAII constructs (like `std::unique_ptr` or containers) for resource acquisition.

## Data structures

- Prefer `std::array` (if size is statically known) or `std::vector` (if not) over raw arrays. This also helps with memory cleanup.
- Try to structure similarly used variables in their own `class` or `struct`.
- Prefer `std::vector` (preferred) or `std::deque` (if constant time frontal insertion/removal is needed) over `std::list`, unless you absolutely need constant time random insertion/removal (and even then, you might want to measure `std::vector` as it is surprisingly efficient on modern hardware).

## Class design

- Some variables have very cryptic names and few (if any) documentation to their meaning.

  - `Graph::V`: Represents the number of vertices in the graph. Maybe rename to `vertex_count` or `num_vertices` or similar.
  - `u` and `w` in `Graph::addEdge`: There is not way to infer whether the edge is added from `u` to `w` or vice versa. Maybe rename to something like `from` and `to`?
  - `Graph::cycle`: `cycle` is an unfornate choice of name, as the verb cycle has a different meaning. `hasCycle` or `findCycle` better express the intention behind this member function.
- There is an implicit assumption that "vertex index" == "vertex value". If there ever is a case where this assumption does not hold, the whole class will have to be redesigned.
- `Graph::cycle` violates the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP). It does two things ("check whether there is a cycle" and "return the cycle"), which might benefit users of the class that want both operations, but hinders other users that only want one of the operations.
- `Graph` is built upon the assumption that no more vertices will be added after construction. While this might be true in your specific use case, this won't be true in general.
- A specific edge might be added multiple times, which might increase worst case runtimes (as iteration of the edges of a vertex can become greater than \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$

## Amending all the points

If I had to implement this, the result would look like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <deque>

class graph {
    using node_type = int;

    class vertex {
        node_type value;
        std::vector<vertex *> edges;
        bool visited = false;
        bool marked = false;

    public:
        vertex(node_type name) : value{name}, edges{} {}

        node_type name() const { return value; }
        bool is_marked() const { return marked; }
        void clear_flags() { visited = false; marked = false; }

        bool has_edge(vertex *to) const {
            return std::find(std::begin(edges), std::end(edges), to) != std::end(edges);
        }
        void add_edge(vertex *to) {
            if(!has_edge(to)) edges.push_back(to);
        }

        vertex *find_first_marked_edge() {
            auto match = std::find_if(std::begin(edges), std::end(edges), [](auto& edge){ return edge->marked; });
            if(match == std::end(edges)) return nullptr;

            return *match;
        }

        bool is_part_of_cycle() {
            if(marked) return true;
            if(visited) return false;

            visited = true;
            marked = true;

            for(auto& edge : edges) {
                if(edge->is_part_of_cycle()) return true;
            }

            marked = false;
            return false;
        }
    };

    std::vector<vertex> vertices;

public:
    graph() = default;
    graph(std::initializer_list<node_type> init) : vertices{} {
        for(auto& name : init) {
            add_vertex(name);
        }
    }

    void add_vertex(const node_type& name) {
        if(std::find_if(std::begin(vertices), std::end(vertices), [&](auto& vert){ return vert.name() == name; }) != std::end(vertices)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"a vertex with this name already exists"};
        }
        vertices.emplace_back(name);
    }

    void add_edge(node_type from, node_type to) {
        auto& from_vert = find_vertex(from);
        auto& to_vert = find_vertex(to);

        from_vert.add_edge(&to_vert);
    }

    bool has_cycle() {
        for(auto& vert : vertices) {
            vert.clear_flags();
        }

        for(auto& vert : vertices) {
            if(vert.is_part_of_cycle()) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    std::deque<node_type> find_first_cycle() {
        auto cycle = std::deque<node_type>{};
        if(!has_cycle()) return cycle;

        auto cycle_iter = find_first_marked_vertex();

        while(std::find(std::begin(cycle), std::end(cycle), cycle_iter->name()) == std::end(cycle)) {
            cycle.push_back(cycle_iter->name());
            cycle_iter = cycle_iter->find_first_marked_edge();
        }

        while(cycle.front() != cycle_iter->name()) cycle.pop_front();

        return cycle;
    }

private:
    vertex& find_vertex(node_type name) {
        auto match = std::find_if(std::begin(vertices), std::end(vertices), [&](auto& vert){ return vert.name() == name; });
        if(match == std::end(vertices)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"vertex could not be found"};
        }

        return *match;
    }

    vertex* find_first_marked_vertex() {
        auto match = std::find_if(std::begin(vertices), std::end(vertices), [](auto& vert){ return vert.is_marked(); });
        if(match == std::end(vertices)) return nullptr;
        return &*match;
    }
};
```

Points to note:

- `graph::vertex` encapsulates all information about a vertex. I changed `recStack` to `marked`, since many graph algorithms work with marked vertices.
- No manual memory management (= no memory leaks). Everything is owned by containers.
- I introduced some descriptive helper functions. This makes the code much more readable.
- If the value of the vertices ever needs to be changed (or templated), only the definition of `graph::node_type` needs to be adjusted.
- For a more deterministic performance, `graph::vertex::edges` could be kept sorted at all times.
- Some functions have a `first` in their names, as there might be more results (in the general case).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate you wrote a sum up with your own version ( I think you just couldn't resist to cose)

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis: It's more that I described all the general steps, but the transformation as a whole is just of this big a scale. Just encapsulating all state in `vertex` is a huge leap that isn't easy to do starting from the original code. Also: "cose"?

Comment: *code , Also just a note you didn't implement a function to set a vector to the path of the cycle .

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis: See `graph::find_first_cycle`. There are many ways to fill a `std::vector` from a `std::deque` (e.g. using `std::copy`), or the implementation could be changed to return a `std::vector` if absolutely needed.

Comment: Yes, thanks I just pointed out as a note not a complain.

Comment: I just think that this is the more general approach: If only iterator is needed, one can directly use a range-for-loop over the result, and only if storage is needed one can either keep the `deque` or transform it as needed. Working with container arguments is always a bit tricky, as you have to specify what happens to elements already present. (Your original code called `path.clear()` at one point, which destroys all previous elements, ehich might not be expected. I'll add this to the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Set your editor to trim trailing whitespace from lines when you save!

---

```
list<int> *adj; // Pointer to array of lists
```

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

```
Graph::~Graph() {  
    delete[] adj;  
}
```

Pointer to array?  You know about vectors, why not use it here?  At the very least, make it a `unique_ptr` to the same kind of raw allocation.

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

Once you do that, you can get rid of the manually supplied destructor.  Everything *in* the class knows what to do.

---

```
adj[u].push_back(w); // Add u to v's list.
```

Isn’t that adding w to u’s list?  Either the comment is pointless (and wrong) because it duplicates what the code says, or it is saying something important but is completely unclear as to what you mean.

---

```
Graph::Graph(int V) {  
    this->V = V;         // Set Graph nodes  
    adj = new list<int>[V]; // V-dimention array of lists  
}
```

Use the member-init list in the constructor!
And, changing `adj` to a vector, we have

```
Graph::Graph(int V)
    : V{V}, adj(V)
{ }
```

---

```
bool Graph::cycleHelper(int v, bool visited[], bool *recStack, vector<int> &path) const {
```

The `visited[]` array notation is actually just passing a pointer, with no length information.  You should pass a container<sup>※</sup> by reference.  You use a different notation for `recStack`, but you use it with subscripts, so this is also really a container.

It is literally cryptic and deceptive to read this declaration and understand what is being passed!  It should be *clear* that they are containers, not pointers to single values; it should bundle the legal size in one name and not be implicit sized by context.

---

```
if (visited[v] == false) {
```

Comparing against a boolean is silly.  The value is already a boolean — use it.

```
if (!visited[v])
```

But, you have the bulk of the function indented under this, and only two lines otherwise.  You have the test backwards — already visited is the special case.

```
if (visited[v]) {
   recStack[v] = false;
   return false;
   }
visited[v] = true;
⋮ etc.  // Note you are back at the top of function scope, not nested in something.
```

---

```
bool *visited = new bool[V];  
bool *recStack = new bool[V];
```

Again, you know how to use `vector`<sup>※</sup>

---

## ※ `vector<bool>` is weird

I just noticed that the times you used raw memory allocations is with `bool`.  So maybe you know this, and are avoiding specifically `std::vector<bool>` specialization.

That’s not clear in the code.  You should document the decision and the problem, and use type alias names to abstract what you actually chose (and can update it easily).

A couple easy work-arounds are

① use `deque` instead
② use a `uint_8` instead of `bool`

But you can also use Boost.Container’s vector class, which does not have the same mis-feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use array instead of vectors where i will have a fixed length, but I understand that if I use vector I will not have to bring up and down  the memory  like when i use  raw array.

Comment: Uh.... I think you got that wrong.  `std::list` is for inserting/deleting from the middle without changing the address of other elements.  It is very slow to use in general.

Comment: I meant array sorry :P

Comment: except you meant why I use list instead of vector in privates?

Comment: Use a `vector` initialized to N elements of some value.  If you *must* save the few bytes by remembering the current size/capacity, use `unique_ptr` of `T[]` in the same manner you use T* now; but that does not make the function call arguments any clearer (the proper thing there would be to use `gsl::span`, but just use `vector`).

Comment: `[boost::container](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/container.html)::vector<bool>` might be good for you.  Construct with `(size, value)` to make it full length allocated, not empty.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will take a look on those. For now I think there is a bug i need to fix.